# How to get values from angular observable?

Tags: angular, rxjs, angular8, rxjs-observables

I have an http response like this:

```
{
  version: "",
  result: {
   pageInfo: {...},
     data: []
  }
}
```

So I am getting this response using an angular service. And using this service in component.

```js
export class UserComponent implements OnInit {
    users$: Observable<User[]>;
    pageInfo$: Observable<PageInfo>;
    
    constructor(private userService: UserService) { }
    
      ngOnInit() {
    
        this.users$ = this.userService.getUsers().pipe(
          /// how to map response for users$ and pageInfo$ ???
          // response.data will be in users$
          // response.pageInfo will be in pageInfo$
        );
    
    }
    
}
```

But I can not map two different observable the response. Is there any practical solution for that?

Comment: The real question is; why would you want 2 observables here anyway..?

Comment: I am binding them seperately to view side. users$ is binding a list as async, pageInfo$ is binding to a paginator component. make sense?

Comment: Yes - but you still wouldn't need 2 then. You can wrap your view with an ng-container with an *ngIf, like *ngIf="response$ | async as response" and then simply use response.users and response.pageInfo.. It's just another option...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Consider applying `shareReplay` operator (Unlike `share` operator where the Observable returned by `this.userService.getUsers()` will be resubscribed when either of the Observables is subscribed after the first has already completed, resulting in further HTTP request,  using `shareReplay` allows access to previously emitted values) as demonstrated below:

```js
users$: Observable<User[]>;
pageInfo$: Observable<PageInfo>;

constructor(private userService: UserService) { }

ngOnInit() {
  const shared$ = this.userService.getUsers()
    .pipe(
      map(({ result }) => result),
      shareReplay(1)
    );

  this.users$ = shared$.pipe(map(({ data }) => data));
  this.pageInfo$ = shared$.pipe(map((pageInfo) => pageInfo));
}
```

Comment: If I use shareReplay in `this.userService.getUsers()` method, do I need again in component as you show?

Comment: You're right, If your goal is preventing a further http request, using `shareReplay` in the service is the best approach

Comment: using `shareReplay` in the service, neither `share` nor `shareReply`  are necessary in the component

Answer (score 0):

Do this. Please note the share-Operator, otherwise the request would be sent twice.

```
export class UserComponent implements OnInit {

  users$: Observable<User[]>;
  pageInfo$: Observable<PageInfo>;

  constructor(private userService: UserService) { }

  ngOnInit() {
    const result$ = this.userService.getUsers().pipe(
      map(response => response.result),
      share();
    );
    this.users$ = result$.pipe(
      map(result => result.data),
    );
    this.pageInfo$ = result$.pipe(
      map(result => result.pageInfo),
    );
  }
}
```

Comment: is there any difference share() and ShareReplay() for using this problem?

Comment: It can make a difference when the service is super fast and emits before the further observables are defined. In this case, you are right, share can lead to undefined within the late subscriber. shareReplay would be safer. However the fast service is just theory and practically very much unlikely. As a result it shouldn't really make difference if share oder shareReplay.

Answer (score 0):

Use ES6 `Destructuring`  feature like this:

> **Component.ts**

```js
this.userService.getUsers().subscribe((res) => {
  let { version, result } = res;
});
```

For more information about `Destructring` visit [this](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Destructuring_assignment) link.